# Apache POI XSLF remove shadow from text on the slide

Tags: java, apache-poi

I got the pptx file with simple presentation. It has background image, white text on it and this text has shadow. I need to simplify presentation and remove all this things (set backgroun to white, font color to black and remove shadows)

Change bachground and font colors are pretty straightforward, like this

```
        SlideShow ppt = SlideShowFactory.create(inputStream);
        List<Slide> slides= ppt.getSlides();
        for (int i = 0; i< slides.size(); i++) {
            Slide slide = slides.get(i);
            ((XSLFSlide)slide).getBackground().setFillColor(Color.white);
            XSLFTextShape[] shapes = ((XSLFSlide) slide).getPlaceholders();
            for (XSLFTextShape textShape : shapes) {
                List<XSLFTextParagraph> textparagraphs = textShape.getTextParagraphs();
                for (XSLFTextParagraph para : textparagraphs) {
                    List<XSLFTextRun> textruns = para.getTextRuns();
                    for (XSLFTextRun incomingTextRun : textruns) {
                        incomingTextRun.setFontColor(Color.black);
                }
            }
```

But i can't figure out how to remove shadows. Here is examle before and after
[image: Before]
 [image: After]

I tried to call `getShadow()` method on TextShape, but it's null, in `XSLFTextRun` there is no methods to manage text shadows. For HSLF i saw that there is `setShadowed()` for `TextRun`. 
But how to deal with shadows in XSLF?

Thanks!

UPDATE:

Thanks Axel Richter for really valuable answer.
In my doc i found two cases with shadowed text.

1. First one is as Axel described, solution is to clean shadow from CTRegularTextRun. Also i find out that `XSLFTextParagraph.getTextRuns()` may contain LineBreak objects, so before casting `XSLFTextRun.getXMLObject()` - it's good idea to check that it's instance of `CTRegularTextRun` and not `CTTextLineBreak`

Code:

```
private void clearShadowFromTextRun(XSLFTextRun run) {
    if (run.getXmlObject() instanceof CTRegularTextRun) {
        CTRegularTextRun cTRun = (CTRegularTextRun) run.getXmlObject();
        if (cTRun.getRPr() != null) {
            if (cTRun.getRPr().getEffectLst() != null) {
                if (cTRun.getRPr().getEffectLst().getOuterShdw() != null) {
                    cTRun.getRPr().getEffectLst().unsetOuterShdw();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

2. Second case - SlideMaster contains some styles definitions for body and title. So if we want remove all shadows competely - we should clear them too.

Code:

```
private void clearSlideMastersShadowStyles(XMLSlideShow ppt) {
    List<XSLFSlideMaster> slideMasters = ppt.getSlideMasters();
    for (XSLFSlideMaster slideMaster : slideMasters) {
        CTSlideMaster ctSlideMaster = slideMaster.getXmlObject();
        if (ctSlideMaster.getTxStyles() != null) {
            if (ctSlideMaster.getTxStyles().getTitleStyle() != null) {
                clearShadowsFromStyle(ctSlideMaster.getTxStyles().getTitleStyle());
            }
            if (ctSlideMaster.getTxStyles().getBodyStyle() != null) {
                clearShadowsFromStyle(ctSlideMaster.getTxStyles().getBodyStyle());
            }
            if (ctSlideMaster.getTxStyles().getOtherStyle() != null) {
                clearShadowsFromStyle(ctSlideMaster.getTxStyles().getOtherStyle());
            }
        }
    }
}

private void clearShadowsFromStyle(CTTextListStyle ctTextListStyle) {
        if (ctTextListStyle.getLvl1PPr() != null) {
            if (ctTextListStyle.getLvl1PPr().getDefRPr() != null)
                if (ctTextListStyle.getLvl1PPr().getDefRPr().getEffectLst() != null)
                    if (ctTextListStyle.getLvl1PPr().getDefRPr().getEffectLst().getOuterShdw() != null)
                        ctTextListStyle.getLvl1PPr().getDefRPr().getEffectLst().unsetOuterShdw();
        }
//same stuff for other 8 levels. Ugly uhh...
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Settings of text shadow is not yet implemented in `XSLFTextRun`. But of course they are set in the `XML`.

A run having shadowed text looks like:

```
<a:r>
 <a:rPr lang="de-DE" smtClean="0" dirty="0" b="1">
  <a:effectLst>
   <a:outerShdw dir="2700000" algn="tl" dist="38100" blurRad="38100">
    <a:srgbClr val="000000">
     <a:alpha val="43137"/>
    </a:srgbClr>
   </a:outerShdw>
  </a:effectLst>
 </a:rPr>
 <a:t>The text...</a:t>
</a:r>
```

As you see there is a `rPr` ( run properties) having a `effectLst` having a `outerShdw` element. We can use `ooxml-schemas` classes and methods to set and unset this.

```
...
      incomingTextRun.setFontColor(Color.black);

      org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.CTRegularTextRun cTRun = (org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.CTRegularTextRun)incomingTextRun.getXmlObject();
      if (cTRun.getRPr() != null) {
       if (cTRun.getRPr().getEffectLst() != null) {
        if (cTRun.getRPr().getEffectLst().getOuterShdw() != null) {
         cTRun.getRPr().getEffectLst().unsetOuterShdw();
        }
       }
      }
...
```

Comment: Thanks! That realy helps. Also I figured out, that some shadows comes from slideMaster styes (for title e.g). So I cleaned shadows from styles too.